# Stop a video file from loading if detect mobile format

Tags: web, responsive-design, html5-video, media

I have a video file as a header, but want to change it to an image when it detects mobile format. Is there a way to do this without using CSS {display: none} at the specified mobile media query?

Comment: is there a specific reason that you don't want to use CSS?

Comment: If you don't like display:none, you'll probably will be not glad to use z-index?

Comment: It would be easy if there's a way to load a video via CSS. {display: none} doesn't stop the browser from loading the file and I would like to reduce the bandwidth for mobile.